# How to connect tronlink deep links for my dapp? The example from the documentation does not work

Tags: deep-linking, web3js, decentralized-applications, tron, tronlink

I'm trying to make a deep link so that from a mobile browser without the TronLink extension I can be transferred directly to the TronLink mobile application, after which I will continue to use the dapp there, but when I click on the link, TronLink just opens and the "External" window appears Error", without any specific information. I noticed that with the same code that I use, the site sunswap.com works smoothly, I don’t understand the reason, perhaps there is some kind of white list dapp that determines whether I can do this or not?

```
const u = {
      url: "some_url.com",
      callbackUrl: "some_callback.com",
      dappName: "Limitless",
      protocol: "TronLink",
      version: "1.0",
      chainId: "0x2b6653dc",
      action: "login",
      actionId: "e5471a9c-b0f1-418b-8634-3de60d68a288",
    };


    const url = "tronlinkoutside://pull.activity?param=".concat(
      encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(u))
    );

    console.log(url);
    return (window.location.href = url);
```

After creating a deep Link, I am transferred to the tronlink application, where my dapp will immediately be opened

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TronLink mobile app has blocked all deeplinks from thirdparties since a update in Aug.2023 (sunswap.com is a TRON official application).

There was a whitelist before and you could email them to add your app host.
We did this before and it worked for a period, but not for now. [Reference](https://github.com/tronprotocol/tronwallet-adapter/issues/30#issuecomment-1736920590)